How to isolate RS485 (A and B) from existing transceiver? Check attached circuit diagram, is it correct?
I have a controller with an RS485 transceiver, specifically the IS8489EIBZ-T, which is not isolated. I want to connect a BMS system to the output of this transceiver. After some research, I found a few ICs that provide the required isolation and chose the IS035 for this purpose.
I have prepared a circuit diagram, but I am unsure how to connect the DE and RE pins of both ICs. Please review my circuit and suggest how to connect these pins correctly. Additionally, if any errors or improvements are needed, I would appreciate your suggestions.
My question might be a bit naïve as I am new to the electronics field; my background is in embedded software development. Your support would be highly appreciated, as I am working on a very important project that requires designing a PCB to achieve isolation.


Cost-wise I think you'll struggle to compete with off the shelf RS485 isolators.

I think there is things to learn by reading Analog Devices application note AN1458 - "Isolated RS-485 Repeater with Automatic Direction Control"

Also TI Designs TIDU590 - Dual Isolated Half-Duplex RS-485 Repeater

And TI Data-rate independent half-duplex repeater design for RS-485

@MrGerber those are excellent, I added them into my answer.

@MrGerberThank you for the outstanding application note. I will definitely refer to all of it.

Why exactly do you have to design this from scratch? An isolated repeater sounds like something you can buy from any of the usual suspects dealing with industrial automation products.

@Lundin purpose is to save the cost

And how are you going to produce this cheaper than Wago, Phoenix et al? To do that, you would have to design the plastic encapsulation etc from scratch as well. And do all the EMC testing from scratch. Do you have a R&D budget of several 100k€? This really smells like a solution looking for a problem that it solves.

@mechaTronicsTech As pr my first comment - you will struggle to create this cheaper than an off the shelf product. Even if you just needed one, and didn't do the product certification and verification as Lundin mentions, just the parts cost and design work would cost you tenfolds of what an off the shelf part costs. Not to mention lead times - off the shelf parts can be delivered to you in a few days.

@MrGerber Could you recommend a reliable product that meets the isolation requirements?

@mechaTronicsTech Product recommendation is not considered on-topic for EE.SE. A google search for "RS485 isolator" should get you in the right direction anyway.

@Lundin The end product will not have an enclosure. I am aware that there are many products on the market that meet my requirements. However, I am currently avoiding using them due to their high cost and a past experience where a product we relied on became obsolete, negatively impacting all our products. Therefore, the goal is to create our own cost-effective solution.

If I've understood your goal, you have a controller device which is half-duplex RS-485 (on the left), and a slave device, similar, on the right.  The controller is not isolated, and you want it to be.
But your question is confusing, as your device on the left is IS8489EIBZ-T, a four-wire, full-duplex device.  But you've drawn 2-wire, half-duplex bus on the right.  If the left-device actually is using full-duplex, listening while talking, you might have additional difficulties connecting with a half-duplex right-device. Could you explain more about what you're connecting?
RS-485 DE and /RE
So in essence you've designed a "repeater", but can't work out how to work the output enables: the reason is that it's not possible from just this information.  We need either a) additional information, or b) additional assumptions.
The best way forward is with the reference design from TI, shown later, which makes simple assumptions about which bus segment is transmitting.
Consider the operation of all 75176-pinout TS-485 transceivers:

From TI 75176 datasheet
D is data input, which is put onto the bus when DE is enabled; R is data output, which is copied from the bus when /RE is enabled.  Your question is all about receiver and transmitter enable.
There are normally three signals from the CPU: TXD ("my signal out"), RXD ("my signal in"), and TXEN ("enable the transmitter").  Half-duplex RS-485 is a bus network with shared medium.  What this means is each device must say when it wants to talk.  Under error conditions, they might talk at the same time, with corresponding error signals on the shared medium.  (The /RE pin of the transceiver is usually connected to the same TXEN from the CPU, so you're not listening when you're transmitting, but sometimes it's enabled so you can listen to the bus and check your signal is uncorrupted.)
The classical TXEN is generated in software: 1) enable transmitter, 2) short pause, 3) drive TXD for signal, 4) short pause, 5) disable transmitter.
When we have, say, a plain, full-duplex RS-232 line without useful handshaking, and we want to use half-duplex, we normally use a timer.  (We detect the first low, the first start bit, and enable TXEN from that point; we keep it enabled until X time after the last low.  This is synthesizing a TXEN from the data.
So, you have to somehow get or synthesize the left TXEN and the right TXEN.  Whether this is possible from the middle, as you have it, depends on what is on the left and the right -- one device, lots of devices, and so on; whether the bus lines are have pull-ups/downs etc.
Consider:

If it fits the usage, you can make a small board which replaces the controller's IS8489EIBZ-T transceiver, and connects via, say, ribbon cable.  Now you have access to the controller's DE and RE and it's pretty straightforward.
If you know the higher level protocols, you can make an upper-level relay with a microcontroller decoding the Modbus (or whatever it is) and recreating it.
If you absolutely must do it in the middle, you'll need to detect "bus is being driven" on each bus, and use that, typically with a microcontroller in the middle, or timers.  This is a RS-485 repeater, sometimes used to extend cable length.

Repeaters
Excellent application notes (from @MrGerber comments) include these documents about relaying and how to do it without a microcontroller in the middle, and the third is TI's full design for what you want.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an-1458.pdf
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt480a/slyt480a.pdf

The first one explains the problem like pretty clearly: "faking" the TXEN:

Texas Instruments design
TI gives a full design.  You could do a lot worse than simply implement what they've done, as they have all the design right down to the PCB layout.

https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00333

Which shows you the answer to the question in your diagram: How to connect /RE and DE?

From TI link above
It might be possible depending on your exact requirements to have only a single isolation layer, which might save components and cost.  For example, if this unit is attached to the left device, it could share ground and power, which should simplify and reduce cost.
Other ideas
Questions to help you move forward:

What is on the left and the right of your middleman?
What is the baud rate?
Can you open the controller?
What is the upper-level protocol?
How many devices do you need?

And finally, regarding circuitry: if you don't need very many, consider getting a ready-made isolated RS-485 module (I use the ones from Digilent, but lots are available.)  Especially if you're not experienced with this, it will save a lot of thinking and effort.
Signal Ground
And as everybody will tell you: you must, must, have grounds joining the devices on an RS-485 bus.

I strongly recommend reading Bob Perrrin's indispensible Art and Science of RS-485, especially the portions about grounding.
A previous question of mine about grounds and isolated RS-485: Puzzle how isolated RS-485 (ADM2582) sends signal without signal ground


You correctly understood that the transceiver on the controller side is not isolated, and I intend to isolate it. In my final setup, there will be one master and one slave. My controller will function as the slave, and there will be a Building Management System (BMS) acting as the master. The communication between these devices will be Modbus over half-duplex RS485, meaning there will be only one task at a time—either listening or talking, but not both simultaneously.

The device on the left is an IS8489EIBZ-T, which is a four-wire full-duplex device. However, my requirement is to use half-duplex communication only. Therefore, I have drawn the half-duplex wiring on the controller side.

Can I connect the DE pins of both ICs to HIGH and the /RE pins to LOW?

"Can I connect the DE pins of both ICs to HIGH and the /RE pins to LOW?"  No.  Otherwise your two middlemen transceivers will always transmit, and your two real devices won't be able to use left bus or right bus.

Are there practical reasons you can't simply implement the TI reference design?

@ jonathanjo I reviewed TI's reference design, but I am concerned about the cost of the BOM and PCB. It should not exceed the price of market-available products.

It all comes down to scale and fitness for any given purpose.  We don't know your scale and costs associated with supply-chain risk driving you to design your own.  I'd be amazed you're able to make a good one for less the existing products.  Consider though: adapting this kind of design into a single-isolation design, if it suits your purpose.  It loses a lot of components.

This will be hard. You cannot know when either side has enabled transmitter and will soon transmit something on bus, you only see when something gets transmitted.
Perhaps if you know about the protocol, you can make a "repeater" with MCU and two UARTs that sits between the two RS-485 buses, and understands about the protocol, data, or sequence of operations etc.
It might be easier to isolate one of the devices internally, or have some other active device that isolates near the controller or device, if they have other interfaces than RS-485 too.
What is missing from your picture is the ground. RS-485 does not work with only two wires. All devices require a common reference between transceivers on the RS-485 side. You need to be sure that you either have a reference between devices like a ground wire, or that both devices are e.g. connected to mains PE so they already share a ground reference.
